# how to delete a tkinter menu separator

Tags: python, tkinter, menu, separator

I was making a project where if a mode is turned on then it shows an extra batch of options which i wanna separate from the rest so i used -:

```
add_separator()
```

function of python tkinter. But the problem is that as this menu only renders when that mode is on, so i can't directly add these things to it.

So i've a function that is called as a postcommand when the menu opens. And it's this function where i render stuff. So if i open my menu again and again, the separators stack on top and don't get deleted.

I've been able to figure out how to delete the other components of my menu but not this.
I also had an idea wherein i added the separator when i initialized the menu, but in that case even when the mode is turned off it shows a separator at the end of the menu.

Edit :
Just to make inform, the problem with me selecting an index is that the number of the options is different at times. As what i am making is a note making program, so this is the part where i store the pen history of only the two past used pens.

Also theres always two pen recommended. This results in there being sometimes 3 and sometimes 4 pen selection options.

So if i consider the index according to 4 items, it can give an error when there are only 3.

But if i consider it according to 3 items then it doesn't look good when there are 4 options.
This is the code for rendering the pen history. There are certain things here that are not clear as not the whole code has been submitted here -:

```
def show_pen_history() :
global pen_history, save_pen_history, pen_history_labels, pen_history_cascade

for j in pen_history_labels :
    m1.delete(j)
try :
    m1.delete(pen_history_cascade)
except :
    pass

pen_history_labels.clear()

if save_pen_history :
    k = 0
    for i in list(pen_history.keys()) :
        pen_definition = i + ' || size: ' + str(pen_history[i]['size']) + '| color: ' + pen_history[i]['color'] + '|'
        if pen_history[i]['size'] == pen_size and pen_history[i]['color'] == pen_color :
            pen_definition = pen_definition + '(currently selected)'
        elif pen_history[i]['type'] == 'recommended' :
            pen_definition = pen_definition + ' (recommended)'
        pen_history_labels.append(pen_definition)
        k += 1
    
    pen_history_cascade = 'Pen History'
    m1.add_cascade(label = 'Pen History')
    
    if len(pen_history) > 1 :
        m1.add_command(label = pen_history_labels[0], command = lambda : set_pen(0))
        m1.add_command(label = pen_history_labels[1], command = lambda : set_pen(1))
    if len(pen_history) > 2 :
        m1.add_command(label = pen_history_labels[2], command = lambda : set_pen(2))
    if len(pen_history) > 3 :
        m1.add_command(label = pen_history_labels[3], command = lambda : set_pen(3))
return
```

Also for the menu part i do this -:

```
m1 = tkinter.Menu(menu, tearoff = 0, postcommand = show_pen_history)
```

If anyone can help plz help.
Also hope you all are safe at the time of this ongoing pandemic.

Comment: Share more code!

Comment: Do you want to delete all the separators in the menu?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You delete a separator the way you delete anything else on a menu - pass the index of the separator to the `delete` method.

For example, this will show a menu with two items separated by a separator:

```
exampleMenu = tk.Menu(menubar)
exampleMenu.add_command(label="foo")
exampleMenu.add_separator()
exampleMenu.add_command(label="bar")
exampleMenu.add_command(label="baz")
```

[image: screenshot with separator]

This deletes the separator:

```
exampleMenu.delete(1)
```

[image: screenshot after deleting separator]

If you do not know the index of the separator, you can use the `type` method to get the type of every index. You can use `.index('end')` to get the numerical index of the last item for the purpose of iterating over the items.

For example, this will remove the first separator that is found:

```
end = int(exampleMenu.index("end"))
for index in range(end):
    if exampleMenu.type(index) == "separator":
        exampleMenu.delete(index)
        break
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem is that its index is unpredictable, every time as the placement of separator depends on the number of options, these options can be from 2 - 4 maximum. As its basically a note making program of mine where here i wanna display the last two pens and two recommended.-->

Comment: <-- So if the two pens haven't yet been selected by the user then it only shows three pens, two recommended and one user defined. And if the user selects one more later then it becomes 4

Comment: this results in there being the chance that if we always consider it 4 it gives error when it's 3 and if we do the vice-versa it doesn't look how we want it when its 4.

Comment: @MatrixProgrammer: yes, of course. The point here is that you need to give the index of the separator. It's up to you to determine what the index is in your specific case.

Answer (score 2):

`Menu` has a attribute called `delete`,You just need to pass a index argument to it.

```
import tkinter as tk

def remove_the_sep():
    sub_menu_bar.delete(1)

app = tk.Tk()
app.geometry('100x100')
menubar = tk.Menu(app, tearoff=False)
sub_menu_bar = tk.Menu(menubar, tearoff=False)
sub_menu_bar.add_command(label="Option1")
sub_menu_bar.add_separator()
sub_menu_bar.add_command(label="Option2")
menubar.add_cascade(menu=sub_menu_bar, label="menu")
app.config(menu=menubar)

tk.Button(app, text="Remove", command=remove_the_sep).pack()

app.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But the problem is that its index is unpredictable, every time as the placement of separator depends on the number of options, these options can be from 2 - 4 maximum. As its basically a note making program of mine where here i wanna display the last two pens and two recommended.-->

Comment: <-- So if the two pens haven't yet been selected by the user then it only shows three pens, two recommended and one user defined. And if the user selects one more later then it becomes 4

Comment: this results in there being the chance that if we always consider it 4 it gives error when it's 3 and if we do the vice-versa it doesn't look how we want it when its 4.